# Mongodb remove does not run in a script

Tags: javascript, mongodb, scripting

I have a javascript file that does the following:

```
var collections = db.getCollectionNames();
for(var i = 0; i < collections.length; i++) {
        var coll = db.getCollection(collections[i]);
        coll.remove({_id : { $lt : queryoid } }); //queryoid is an objectId from a datetime
}
```

I load it into the Mongo shell like this:

```
mongo test --eval "load('deleteLogs.js')"
```

However, nothing gets removed. If I replace the remove with a find and count the returned results instead, it returns numbers. What's wrong here?

EDIT:

```
function objectIdWithTimestamp(dateTime) {

        var hexSeconds = Math.floor(dateTime/1000).toString(16);
        var constructedObjectId = ObjectId(hexSeconds + "0000000000000000");

        return constructedObjectId
}

var oneMonthBefore = new Date();
oneMonthBefore.setMonth(oneMonthBefore.getMonth() - 1);
var queryoid = objectIdWithTimestamp(oneMonthBefore);
```

Comment: Are you sure? I tried on my MongoDB 2.2.6. It works fine.

Comment: why are you using eval and load?  Why not just run mongo test deleteLogs.js?

Comment: btw, where are you defining 'queryoid' variable?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky I also tried using mongo test deleteLogs.js, I also updated my question to show my created objectId

Comment: wrap remove in printjson like this:  printjson(coll.remove({ etc }) ); then you will see what result it's returning (if it includes ok:0 then command isn't running properly... or you might see ok:1 (command ran) but err:"some err" and n:X will be the number of records affected.